# AngularJS - One controller on two sibling DOM elements

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a very simple thing. I'm displaying a list of values with Edit links beside them. Clicking the edit link reveals a form that lets you update the value.

(I've simplified the question so the items just have one field "name". My actual use case has more fields, but is canonically equivalent.)

I've run into something that looks like a bug in Angular, but given my limited experience with it, I'm not so sure. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ctrl" ng-hide="ctrl.isEditing">
    <span>Name: {{item.name}}.</span>
    <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.startEditing()'>Edit</a>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-show="ctrl.isEditing">
    <input type='text' ng-model='item.name'/>
    <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.save()'>Save</a>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('ItemController', function() {
    this.isEditing = false;
    this.startEditing = function() { this.isEditing = true; }
    this.save = function() { this.isEditing = false; }
});
```

Clicking on `Edit` link calls the right controller function, and the first `div` hides. But the second `div` does not hide.

When I rearrange the code to look like this (essentially wrapping the two `div`s with a wrapper element), all is well.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-hide="ctrl.isEditing">
        <span>Name: {{item.name}}.</span>
        <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.startEditing()'>Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="ctrl.isEditing">
        <input type='text' ng-model='item.name'/>
        <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.save()'>Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what is technically wrong with the first version? Note that the `<input>` boxes do get populated with the right values from `item.name`.

PS: There's a reason why I'm trying to keep the two `div`s siblings: in my use case, they are actually implemented as two `tr`s which are supposed to appear right below each other in a table.

Comment: first code snippet: the controller scope ends with the first div. hence the second div will not hide, moreover second div has condition ng-show="ctrl.isEditing", hence it will remain true and will show up if using ng-show. Second case, the controller scope ends with the wrapper div.

Comment: I thought so too. But if that was the case, I'd not expect the `<input>` in the second `div` to not get populated either. But it happens to have the right item names populated. So perhaps the second `div`'s `<input>`s getting populated is a bug?

Comment: The only other explanation I can think of is that `ngEach` has a different scope than `ngController` even though they both are declared on the same DOM element (in the first snippet)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug from angular but it is quite logical.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ctrl" ng-hide="ctrl.isEditing">
    <span>Name: {{item.name}}.</span>
    <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.startEditing()'>Edit</a>
</div>

<div ng-repeat-end ng-show="ctrl.isEditing">
    <input type='text' ng-model='item.name'/>
    <a href='#' ng-click='ctrl.save()'>Save</a>
</div>
```

If you see the above code you have injected controller only to the first div so obviously sibling div doesn't know what is ctrl or ItemCtrl until and unless you do as in you second way.

So if you want to achieve it as sibling, if you are using routing then add the controller attribute in your route path.

So that the controller will be active for that entire template and you can achieve what you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought so too. But if that was the case, I'd not expect the `<input>` to get populated either. But it happens to have the right item names populated..

Answer (score 1):

Thats because controller has its own scope. When you placed controller ONLY on your first `div` controllers' scope is limited to only this one `div`. When you wrapped both your `divs` inside another and place controller on wrapper, controllers' scope now is all that inside this wrapper. So in this case this works fine and this is not the angular bug